# How do I input a .data file to Tensorflow image classifier?

Tags: python, file, tensorflow, machine-learning, training-data

How do I load a dataset of images with .data extension into my Tensorflow classifier coded using Google Colab?

I'm trying to classify benign / malignant thyroid nodules using the University of California Irvine machine learning repository dataset.

I've seen several tutorials for loading data, but that is all as a zip file.

Mainly stuff like this:

```
download = drive.CreateFile({'id': '1BZOv422XJvxFUnGh-0xVeSvgFgqVY45q'})
download.GetContentFile('train_LbELtWX.zip')
!unzip train_LbELtWX.zip
```

How do I do the equivalent with a .data file?

Thanks!

Comment: @fgoncalved, if i am not wrong the file already present in your drive ?

Comment: It is in my drive / stored to my computer.

Comment: Then use something like this : `from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/allbp.data') as myfile:
     x = myfile.read()

data = x.split('\n')
   `